# Can we modify this extended pseudometric such that its convergence is equivalent to that in measure?

Tags: measure-theory, limits-and-convergence, metric-spaces

Below we use [Bochner measurability](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_measurable_function) and [Bochner integral](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_integral). Let

- $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a complete $\sigma$-finite measure space,
- $(E, | \cdot |)$ a Banach space,
- $S (X)$ the space of $\mu$-simple functions from $X$ to $E$, and
- $L^0 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-measurable functions from $X$ to $E$.
- $L^1 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-integrable functions from $X$ to $E$.

For $\delta >0$, we write
$$
\begin{align*}
\{|f - g| > \delta\} &:= \{x \in X : |f (x) - g(x)| > \delta\}, \\
\mu (|f - g| > \delta) &:= \mu (\{|f - g| > \delta\}).
\end{align*}
$$

For $f, g \in L^0 (X)$, we define
$$
\begin{align*}
\rho (f, g) &:= \int_X \min\{|f-g|, 1\} \, \mathrm d \mu,\\
\hat \rho (f, g) &:= \inf_{\delta >0} \{ \mu (|f - g| > \delta)  +\delta \}.
\end{align*}
$$

Then $\rho$ and $\hat \rho$ are [extended pseudometrics](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Metric_space#Generalizations_of_metric_spaces) on $L^0 (X)$. Let $f_n, f \in L^0(X)$. We call

- **(S1)** $f_n \to f$ [in measure](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Convergence_in_measure#Definitions), i.e.,
  $$
  \mu ( |f_n - f| > \delta) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0
  \quad \forall \delta >0.
  $$
- **(S2)** $\hat\rho (f_n, f) \to 0$.
- **(S3)** $\rho (f_n, f) \to 0$.

I already proved [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4754273/convergence-in-a-complete-measure-is-metrizable) **(S1)** $\iff$ **(S2)**. For $\delta \in (0, 1)$, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\rho (f_n, f) &= \int_{\{|f_n - f| > \delta\}} \min\{|f_n-f|, 1\} \, \mathrm d \mu + \int_{\{|f_n - f| \le \delta\}} \min\{|f_n-f|, 1\} \, \mathrm d \mu \\
&\ge \delta \mu (|f_n - f| > \delta) + \int_{\{|f_n - f| \le \delta\}} \min\{|f_n-f|, 1\} \, \mathrm d \mu.
\end{align*}
$$

Then **(S3)** $\implies$ **(S1)**. If $\mu(X) < \infty$ [then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4753870/a-characterization-of-convergence-in-a-finite-measure) **(S3)** $\iff$ **(S1)**.

> Is it true that **(S1)** $\implies$ **(S3)**? If not, can we "slightly" modify the definition of $\rho$ such that **(S1)** $\implies$ **(S3)**?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!